# Many/Much more difficult problems

Tags: adjectives

Pick the correct sentence:

1. There were *many* more difficult problems than we were thought possible.
2. There were *much* more difficult problems than we were thought possible.

I think both are correct. The first sentence talks about the amount of problems, 
**many more problems**, while the second sentence talks about difficulty, the problems were **much more difficult**.

Is my reasoning correct? If so, is one of the sentences more correct than the other, e.g. is one of the two more formal than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Side note: You shouldn't say,  "than we were thought possible", just "than we thought possible", or if you prefer "than we were thinking was possible".

But to your question: You are exactly correct. "Many more difficult problems" means that there were a large number of problems. We didn't just have 1 or 2 problems, we had 10 or 20. "Much more difficult problems" means that each problem was more difficult. We might still have had only 2 or 3 problems, but each problem was very difficult.

Neither is better than the other because they mean different things. Use the one that matches the meaning you want to convey.

Comment: "th**e**n we were thinking was possible"?

Comment: how about "th**e**n we were thought"?