# When to use "much more" or "many more"?

Tags: grammar

Under which circumstances would you use "much more" instead of "many more" ? For example would this be correct:

> I have much more money.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Many is for items: "I have many cans of beer," much is for amounts: "I have so much beer".  Or in your example you could go either way:  "I have very many dollar bills" OR "I have very much money" are both correct ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Many/Much more difficult problems](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33895/many-much-more-difficult-problems)

Comment: @user3169 That question is about a certain phrase, and doesn't cover what's being asked here. (Though it does give a couple examples that might help.)

Comment: @DanGetz True, but a better question would discuss the rule (in this case *much* vs. *many*) more generally. Restricting the concern to one phrase is basically proofreading.

Comment: @user3169 I don't think this question asks only to proofread a single phrase, and didn't mean to imply that. I think it's asking for the general rule(s) that would apply in situations such as this. The question you linked is certainly related to this question, but I don't think it answers what's being asked here.

Answer (score 6):

I have much more money.

The OP's sentence is grammatically correct.

You use "much more" in front of an uncountable noun. Another example: I need much more time to do this job.  On the other hand, you use "many more" in front of plural nouns such as I have many more friends in this city.

Answer (score -5):

Much more is a colloquial term. It is acceptable for informal English.

Comment: There's no way you can consider "much more" to be only *colloquial*. It's just normal English, [useful in all registers](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13880/usage-of-much-more).